# How do I instruct Scala's regex matcher to select the leftmost alternation

Tags: regex, scala, regex-alternation

I have hit a regular expression alternation problem when attempting to retrieve a value from `scala.util.matching.Regex`. I have tried both the default and the `unanchored` initialized states while using the `findAllMatchIn` method.

Using the regex pattern of `(1e)|(a1)` with the sample text of `a1e`, I WANT to receive `1e` because **I have placed it in the first alternation position**. I'm confused as to why I am actually receiving the value `a1` instead **which is in the second alternation position**.

After looking through a number of questions that deal with multiple matches across an input string, I have not found any that address **how to handle alternation other than to put them in the right order**, which I have done.

What method(s), if any, can I use to either get back my desired value of `1e`, or that returns two values, one for each of the alternations it matched?

Below is the code sample from my IntelliJ Scala Worksheet ([here's the code in Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tqgE67plQBCFHNrTjyCRWA)):

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val regexStringLongOrLat: String =
  """(1e)|(a1)"""
val regexLongOrLat: Regex = regexStringLongOrLat.r.unanchored

val sample =
  "a1e"

val test2 =
  regexLongOrLat
    .findAllMatchIn(sample)
    .toList

println(test2) //This should return List(1e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns `"a1"` because that's the first match encountered as the regex engine traverses the string.

In this case you can get what you want with a negative look-ahead.

```
"(1e|a1(?!e))".r
              .findAllIn("a1e")
              .toList
//res0: List[String] = List(1e)
```

Note: `"(a1(?!e)|1e)".r` returns the same results.

Comment: Excellent! Tysvm! While I don't exactly understand what you have written, at least now I know what to go study.